# jQuery selector for rails render file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm Implementing Ajax with Rails by adding a new post in runtime without refreshing the page.
The problem is I want to render a specific view by this script which is allocated in `create.js.erb`

```
 $('<%=render(:file => "posts/post.html.erb)%>').insertBefore($('.posts').children('div.post-box').first());
```

But it doesn't work, Can anyone tell me what's wrong on this script and how to select html code in jquery from a specific view?

and this's the `create` action

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.js             
    end
end
```

Comment: Which rails/ruby versions are you using. And where is this piece of code coming from?

Comment: @Max ruby 1.9.3 , rails 3.2.5, and I put the create action up there

Comment: Is this what you need http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2. Look at the helper method: link_to_add_fields() and the js function add_fields. So basically you're trying to add a new post with AJAX?

Comment: No, that's not what i need, all i need is how to select render html in post.html.erb view ??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. This `$('<%=render(:file => "posts/post.html.erb)%>')` construct is wrong. You cannot mix Ruby with JS. Not sure what the controller should do either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is add `escape_javascript` method, just like this

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:file => "posts/post.html.erb"))%>').insertBefore($('.posts').children('div.post-box').first());
```